# DRM standard receiving on shortwave

Tags: receiver, swl

What's the particularities of receiving SW-broadcasting, that uses DRM standard ?

Every SW-receiver can directly receive this kind of signal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not every shortwave radio can receive DRM. A basic shortwave receiver will only support AM, conventional analog shortwave broadcasting. DRM (as well as SSB, another additional mode) are additional features that you should ensure are mentioned on the receiver's feature list before buying.